# Display custom variables

Tags: theming

We have a twig template, `node--page.html.twig` where we want to display the custom variable `ns-custom-template`. The variable is created from a custom module, `mymodule` with the following code below.

**How can I create a variable, populate it using the `ns-custom-template` variable, and display it in the `node--page.html.twig` template?**

Here is what I tried, but when using `kint(test_var)` I get `NULL` returned.

**mymodule.module**

```
function mymodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return [
    'ns_custom_template' => [
      'variables' => [
        'test_var' => NULL,
      ],
    ],
  ];
}
```

**Inside mymodule's template folder is `ns-custom-template.html.twig`**

```
<p> Testing my variable {{ test_var }} </p>
```

**MyModuleController class**

```
class MyModuleController extends ControllerBase {
  public function content() {
    $config = $this->config('mymodule.settings');
    $config_value = $config->get('my_config_value');
    return [
      '#theme' => 'ns_custom_template',
      '#test_var' => $config_value,
    ]
  }
}
```

**mymodule's routing file:**

```
mymodule.module_controller_content:
  path: '/mymodule/content'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\mymodule\Controller\MyModuleController:content'
    _title: 'content'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

**MyModuleForm**

```
class MyModuleForm extends ConfigFormBase {
  protected function getEditableConfigName() {
    return [
      'mymodule.setting',
    ],
  }

  public function getFormId() {
    return 'mymodule_form';
  }

  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $config = $this->config('mymodule.setting');
    $form['my_config_value'] = [
      '#type' => 'textarea',
      '#title' => $this->t('My config value'),
      '#description' => $this->t('Enter some value'),
      '#default_value' => $config->get('my_config_value'),
    ];
    return parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);
  }

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    parent::submitForm($form, $form_state);

    $this->config('mymodule.setting')
      ->set('my_config_value', $form_state->getValue('my_config_value'))
      ->save();
  }
}
```

**node--page.html.twig**

```
<article>
  {{ ns_custom_template }} {# returns null #}
  {{ kint(ns_custom_template }} {# returns null #}
</article>
```

For reference, I am trying to emulate the steps on [Define a custom template for module output](https://docs.acquia.com/tutorials/fast-track-drupal-8-coding/define-custom-template-module-output/) page.

Comment: you code almost there, i test it without the form, it works, Just rename your template from `template`  to `templates` i think. and try to dump the value of `$config_value` inside the `content` method.

Comment: @berramou are you sure it is working? i removed the form and `'#test_var' => $this->t('some value')`, and did `{{ kint(test_var) }}` but it still returned `null`. Any other steps I missed?

Comment: yeah it works for me, don't forget to flush all caches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable you are looking for is not `ns_custom_template` but `test_var`

To get all variables in your twig file, you can try `{{ kint() }}`

To get the variable you have previously declared in `mymodule_theme`, you can try `{{ kint(test_var) }}`

BUT there is another mistake:

The twig file in which you will find `test_var` is not `node--page.html.twig` but only `ns-custom-template.html.twig`

if you want to have `test_var` inside `node--page.html.twig`, you can use a preprocess function : [function template_preprocess_node](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/8.6.x/search/preprocess_node) with a code like:

```
$var['test_var']='my value';
```

EDIT:It seems that you would like to use the template `ns_custom_template` in a node template: to achieve this, you need to populate your variable `test_var` with a render array having the name defined in `mymodule_theme` as a value of the `#theme` key.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_node(&$var) {
  $var['my_free_var_name'] = ['#theme' => 'ns_custom_template', '#test_var' => 'your value'];
}
```

After doing this, you can display your template inside `node--page.html.twig` bu using the following code:

```
{{ my_free_var_name }}
```

Comment: are you suggesting that in the `mymodule_preprocess_node` hook, I just get the `config_object`, use `$var['myvariable'] = $config_value`, and in the `node--page.html.twig` file I print it using `{{ myvariable' }}`? 

That sounds different then what I am trying to accomplish. I would like to create a `variable` that i can theme using `ns-custom-template.html.twig`, and then pass that onto the `node--page.html.twig` using `mymodule`. Is your suggestion the only way to do this?

Comment: @usernameabc, in node preprocess: `$var['test_var'] = ['#theme' => 'ns_custom_template', '#test_var' => $config_value];`

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: @Baud in doing this, I have found that the `MyModuleController` class is not used. Is that correct to expect the `controller` not to be needed anymore given that I would be using `hook_preprocess_node()`?

Comment: If you want to display a variable inside a node template, you do not need to create a route or a controller as everything is already setup by the node module. But if you would like to create a config form that will save some settings (that could be used in the node template), you will need to create a new route to this form (no need to create a controller if you use the _form key... but this is another topic)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to display twig template inside another, for instance `ns-custom-template.html.twig` inside `node--page.html.twig` you should use `include` instead of `{{ some-twig-name }}`:
In your case **node--page.html.twig** will be something like:

```
<article>
  {% include  '/modules/custom/mymodule/templates/ns-custom-template.html.twig' %}
</article>
```

I assume that your module reside in `/modules/custom` folder.

Comment: for some reason this does not return the field I was expecting when i do `{{ ksm() }}`

Comment: Where you put `{{ ksm() }}` ??

Comment: I tried in both `ns-custom-template.html.twig` and `node--page.html.twig`

Comment: if you do something like `{{ kint(test_var) }}` inside  `ns-custom-template.html.twig` you should get the value of the var, did you flush the cache?